изменить переменную (массив) в модуле javascript
модуль iconsCollection
let iconsCollection = [];
export {iconsCollection};

много модулей с иконками manyModules
import {iconsCollection}
iconsCollection.push(someOneIcon);

Нужно чтобы *массив iconsCollection изменялся в модуле iconsCollection после push в модулях manyModules и этот массив iconsCollection мог быть экспортирован дальше в другой модуль

Массивы передаются по ссылкам, поэтому при изменении его в одном месте, изменения будут видны везде. А с чем у вас сложности возникли?

Собственно ровно так оно и работает.

Ну и опишите, что такое у вас модули + добавьте пример для понимания и воспроизведения


Нужно чтобы модуль iconsCollection изменялся после push

Не модуль, а массив. В остальном так и работает.

много модулей с иконками

Кто-то должен их импортировать. Причём до того как

дальше в другой модуль

